# cant access iss with external ip in lan

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking

hello I created a website with IIS. I open ports and everything. I can access this website from another network with ip and port
like http://81.215.xx.xx:81 . but with any computer with same network (LAN) I cant access http://81.215.xx.xx:81 like this. I can only access when I write the static ip of that machine. like http://192.168.1.3:81/
I want to access with external ip in lan how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your LAN most likely has another equipment, a router for example which has an interface with the other IP address, http://81.215.xx.xx:81. Your router forwards requests to your server based on its routing table. This routing does not exist when you are in the private network. That is why you can only access the server with its private IP address which is in the same range as your computer when you are in that network.

Comment: is there no way to access with external ip?

Comment: Connect to a machine outside the LAN and from there connect to your server with the public IP and port. This way your request has to go through the router and so the routing takes place. I am not sure but I think you can also access it with Tor.